# The one who `new/malloc` should `delete/free`?

Tags: c++, ifstream, delete-operator

It seems to be a common sense in C/C++ that, the function which `new/malloc` some memory should `delete/free` them before the function finishes, right?

But suppose I have this kind of problem that, there is a function `reader` which will read chunks from a file into buffers, there is another function `consumer` will consume these buffer latter,

```
void reader(ifstream &ifs)
{
    char *buf = new char[100];
    ifs.read(buf, 100);
    save_buffer(buf);  //save this buf into a global array, say buf_array[10]
}

void consumer()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        consume( buf_array[i] );  //do something with those buffers read by reader
}
```

My problem is, many memory resources are `new`ed inside `reader`, but `reader` cannot `delete` them, because these buffers haven't been used by `consumer`. Should `consumer` be responsible for `delete`ing those buffers?

Comment: If you are using c++11, move semantics can help with this.

Comment: @VaughnCato, thanks, but I'm not using it right now.

Comment: I would just recommend making it clear who is responsible --  who owns the memory at any point in time.  You can use names that contains words like "acquire" and "release" to indicate that ownership is being transferred.  The owner should make sure the memory is freed.

Comment: It gets even more difficult with multithreaded apps.  Trying to return buffer objects to the thread/function that originally raised them can get very messy.  A buffer may have been raised by an opaque library, API or some pool thread somewhere. So, realistically impossible in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

No one said the function that allocates memory should free the memory.  But generally the same component should handle it.  Because your `reader` and `consumer` form a pair, it is fine for them to coordinate the memory together.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to be a common sense in C/C++ that, the function which `new/malloc` some memory should `delete/free` them before the function finishes, right?

No, this is not necessarily true, you do not have to release memory in the same function, as long as you release it eventually before the program ends.

One common solution available in C++ (but not in C) is to deallocate memory in the destructor.  If you pass around objects that contain dynamically allocated memory while dealing correctly with the copy/move constructors and assignment operators, the memory will be released when the destructor is called.

Comment: To release memory in destructor, I should have a data member, say `char *buffers`, but I cannot make sure how many buffers allocated during the program's execution, there might be one or more. So, in destructor, should I use `delete buffers` or `delete [] buffers`?

Comment: @Alcott The idea is to attach a malloc-ed data to its own object, the way it is done in `std::string`. If you alloc multiple buffers, you'd create multiple objects, one per buffer. Again, `std::string` is a very good example of the technique.

Comment: It's not necessary to release memory before the program ends.  What is important is that the program does not lose track of memory while it is running, ie leak:(  Explictly releasing all memory before the app exits is often, err.. 'very, very, very difficult', (trying not to use the 'i' word:).

Answer (score 1):

The principle is that "for every `new`, there should be a `delete`". That doesn't say anything about both calls having to be within the same function (obviously, that wouldn't be very useful).

There's no problem with your example with the reader allocating and the consumer freeing.

Comment: What about this, `reader` is `class A`'s member function, it allocates memory, and `consumer` is `class B`'s member function, it releasees the memory, is it ok?

Comment: If you want to do that, pass via std::auto_ptr to make it clear that ownership is being transferred.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do `new/malloc`(allocation) and `delete/free`(release) in the same function. As long as your algorithm guarantees that every allocation does get released and only gets released once, so that it does not cause memory-leak, it is fine.
In fact, often the allocation and release do exist in separate functions. 
Just remember these: 
1. Use the same pointer to do the release(you can pass the pointer around of course). If you do some arithmetic on the pointer and then release the allocation using that modified pointer, it would produce an error even the pointer still points in the allocation region.
2. As mentioned above, you should guarantee that the allocation got released, and only once. Additional release causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need not free an allocated buffer in the same function in which you initialized it, as long as you carry around a pointer to the buffer.

In your case, `consumer()` should be responsible for `delete`ing the buffers allocated by `consumer`.

As for your secondary question, consumer doesn't know where the buffer ends; you need to tell it somehow. Instead of just storing pointers to the buffers, you might consider defining a new `struct` encapsulating both a buffer and its length. This has already been done: consider looking at using `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different answer to everyone else:

Yes it is fine for the Reader not to free/delete the memory in the reading function, but I wouldn't have the consumer delete the memory. In a simple case works, but what if you have multiple consumers (e.g. to output in different formats)? If consuming the data has the side effect of freeing it, then you cannot do anything else with the data after the fist consumer does it's thing.

I would have a `cleanup()` type method in my reader that I explicitly call to cleanup the buffers when required. This way the module that allocates the memory is responsible for freeing it (even though it is in a different method).

e.g.

```
Data d = Reader.read();
Consumer1.consume(d);
Consumer2.consume(d);
Reader.cleanup(d);
// d is no longer valid.
```

Comment: In such a case, I would probably add a ref. count N to the object before posting it off to its N handlers.  The handlers call some release() method of the object. The last handler to complete will dec the count to zero in release() and delete() the object.  A shared_ptr would do this, if available.  If you have to refCount explicitly, it may be necessary to use atomic instructions for the dec.  AFAIK, shared_ptr is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the contents of buf to a global array buf_arrray which actually feeds the consumer. So, in the example above reader can free the buf.

And, it is not requrired that the function that new/mallocs should be freeing up the memory. The pointer can be passed around. The function that last uses the memory allocated needs to free it the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could also read about shared arrays http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm

Using shared arrays, you can allocate them inside a function and pass them by value to other functions. The shared array keeps an internal count of how many times it has been referenced, and deletes the memory automagically when all references have gone out of scope.

eg

```
void bar( boost::shared_array< int > );

void foo()
{
    boost::shared_array< int > x ( new int[ 100 ] );
    bar( x );
    // because x has been passed to bar(), its reference count is incremented
    // and it will not only be deleted when everyone is finished with it!

    // do more things with x
} // the memory held by x is deleted

void bar( boost::shared_array< int > y )
{
    // Do things with y here
} // the memory held by y is not deleted here because foo() hasn't yet finished
```

Answer (score 0):

In descending order of preference you'd prefer to:

1. Use `auto` storage class, so deletion happens automatically.
2. Have the same same code allocate and delete objects.
3. Pass ownership, so one component allocates and another frees.
4. Have shared ownership via something like `shared_ptr`.

3 and 4 are nearly tied, but both are quite a ways behind 2, which is quite a ways behind 1.

In this case, what you'd really *prefer* is for the level of function (or class, etc.) above both the producer and consumer to allocate the buffers, start the producer and consumer, and delete the buffers when both are finished:

```
class buffer { 
     std::vector<char> data;
public:
     buffer() : data(100) {}
};

process_file(std::string const &name) { 
    std::vector<buffer> buffers(10);

    std::ifstream in(name);

    std::pair<std::ifstream *, std::vector<buffer> *> thread_data = {
        &in, &buffers
    };

    prod = start_thread(producer, (void *)&thread_data);
    cons = start_thread(consumer);
    join(prod);
    join(cons);
}
```

If you can do this, it can help avoid a *lot* of headaches in managing the memory.